# Restore root access to MySQL on Drupal Server

Tags: mysql, drupal, phpmyadmin, drupal-7, acquia

Context: I am new to Drupal. I am working within the Acquia Development App environment. After I was done with the Drupal installation process, I imported a database that I wanted to work with (from a safe tutorial). When I tried to see the site after the db import Drupal gave me an error message that it could not find the database.

Problem: I went to phpadmin to check what was going on and after trying some things I accidentally deleted all users, including the root. Now I am trying to start a new Drupal site installation from scratch with Acquia but I get the following message: "MySQL Error:Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)".

**I have no idea how to regain access to MySql and restore my root user**

Here is the sequence of steps on the Acquia App:
[image: Step 1]

[image: Step 2-- start from scratch]

[image: Step 3 -- import Drupal 7.39]

[image: Step 4 -- create site]

[image: Error message]

Any help is welcome.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you deleted a user account in mySQL, you can recreate it using a SQL command

```
CREATE USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'some_password';
```

Then grant permissions to the new user

```
GRANT ALL ON *.DB_NAME TO 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'some_password';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should reinstall Acquia DevDesktop as this will re-configure the local MySQL installation.  You won't be able to authenticate (as no root user exists for which you have credentials) with MySQL to update the root account as otherwise suggested.